# Nodemon -e does not fire with the given extensions

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I am trying to add watcher for `nodemon` for more extensions like `js,hbs`,

when I run `nodemon` with those argument `nodemon -e js,hbs` its should be watch for changes on `.js,.hbs` files.

There is an output which shows `nodemon` get those parameters, but nothing happen.

```
C:\Users\97252\WebstormProjects\web-server\src>nodemon app.js -e js,hbs
[nodemon] 2.0.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,hbs
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Server is up on port 3000.
```

After changing file with extension `.js,.hbs` its not auto refresh the code at all.

Comment: add a config for nodemon

Comment: @frozen, how do i get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was running `nodemon` from the folder `src`, which mean the js,hbs is not on the current route.

I have run the `nodemon` from `web-server` instand of `web-server/src`.

that fixed the problem because the `js,hbs` files are inside this folder.